# video stops on opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am currently trying to show a video on Python OpenCV. However, although it shows the selected video with below code, for some reason the video just stops after 15 sec or so. 
I have checked RAM but it seems it's quite stable.

Environments are: **Anaconda3(Python 2.7.13), Windows 7, OpenCV 3.2.0**

What I tried is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Traffic2.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior with a gopro video I am working with.  I found that after letting it run for a while (not advancing frames, but just running and sometimes for up to 5 minutes), it resumes playback like normal.  I would love to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the posted code on a .avi file on my computer, it is *running completely fine*.Can you please run the code with another video of.avi type or .mp4 type.

I predict that the problem **may be due to video issue or video codec issue**, there is **no error in the code**.